# how display specific data from db in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have two Model `user` and `speed`

**User Model** contain

`name`,`email`,`password`,`id_watch` all this get from **sign up** In addition to `user_id`

**speed Model** contain

`id_watch`,`x_speed`,`y_speed` all this already add by watch device

**need** when user sign up  then enter `id_watch` get all `id_watch` data

when `id_watch` from `user table` equal `id_watch` from `speed table`

Comment: `Speed.where(id_watch: current_user.id_watch)` nor use `.find` if want to return just one `id_watch`

Comment: must association between two table @ 7urkm3n ?

Comment: as i understand, you dnt need assoc' for this kind part.

Comment: yes but i asked you must or not ?

Comment: if speed model is just public data and want to make sure user interest == to public data then no need. It all depends how modeling an application.

Comment: user must have only one id_watch for example user(name: hello) have id = "#21"

Comment: @ 7urkm3n can write answer and accepted this thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create smth like this. Association is not important for this.

```
#view pages
<% @speed_data.each do |sd| %>
   <%= "#{sd.x_speed} : #{sd.y_speed}" %>
<% end %>

#in controller where using current_user or user object
#sample
def index
   @speed_data = current_user.speed_data
end

# models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
   def speed_data
      Speed.where(id_watch: self.id_watch)
   end
end

# models/speed.rb
class Speed < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: Thanks you @7urkm3n